# Get rid of long require strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

In PHP, I used to do things like this :

```
<?php

use Vendor/Namespace/Bundle;
$bundle = new Bundle();
```

What interests me here is that, following the PSR-4 convention (or any other convention), we could automatically require a PHP file and use its content. Is there any ways to do this in Javascript, or how to do not use some ugly `require('../../../../../../../mymodule.js');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `$NODE_PATH` variable to whichever location you want `require` to look into by default.

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

For e.g. setting it to `/user/project/lib;` you can do a `require('mymodule.js')` from, say `/user/project/test/test.js`, it'll work.

Comment: I just tested your proposal, it works when I define my `NODE_PATH` n the terminal, but when doing `console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH = __dirname +'/src'); require('MA/MessagesBundle/MessagesBundle');` it does not work.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate it doesn't work that way. Probably because it's read before `require()` itself initializes and once it has it doesn't matter if you change it like that later. You can just pass `process.env.NODE_PATH` to the `require()` as an argument if you're only setting it from within your app.